# Updating $Scope variable between two aspx web page

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, angularjs-scope, asp.net-4.5

I have a search page , once user clicks Search button it calls an angualrjs function, where I need to update some $scope variables and redirect to another page.

This is my service to share the object between controllers

```
    var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['angular.filter', 'googlechart']);
app.factory('sharedService', function () {
var testObj = {
    name:'User Name 1',
    age: 25
};

var searchParameter = function (newObj) {        
    testObj = newObj;

};

var getParameter = function () { 
    return  testObj;
    };

    return {
        searchParameter: searchParameter,
        getParameter: getParameter
    };
});
```

Here is the Controller 1 : SearchController

```
app.controller('SearchController', function ($scope, $parse, $filter, $location, $window, sharedService) {

$scope.searchParameter = function (searchParameter) { 
    var testObj = {
        name: 'UserName 2',
        age: 35
    };
    sharedService.searchParameter(testObj);        
        $window.location.href = 'http://localhost:8080/UI/SearchResult.aspx';      
    }
});
```

And this is my controller 2 : ResultController

```
app.controller('ResultController', function ($scope, $parse, $filter,  sharedService) {  
    $scope.getParameter = function () {       
        $scope.testParam = sharedService.getParameter();        
    }
});
```

testObj is a model.

It is redirecting to the result page, but the testObj value is not getting updated to UserName 2.

How can I get updated value in the controller 2?

Answer (score 0):

This is not working because in your service, the object is declared as var. So even if you're updating from outside, it will not return the value.
Also apart from service, if your pages are like parent-child controller, you can share objects between controller. Let me know if service solution is not working, I can share solution for sharing objects between controllers.

The variable should be bound to the service. Something like below:

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['angular.filter', 'googlechart']);
app.factory('sharedService', function () {
    this.testObj = {
      name:'User Name 1',
     age: 25
    };

var searchParameter = function (newObj) {        
   this.testObj = newObj;  
};

 var getParameter = function () { 
    return  this.testObj;
 };

   return {
      searchParameter: searchParameter,
      getParameter: getParameter
    };
 });
```